# como guardo los valores de una tabla a un vector de string? c#

Tags: c#

contexto: necesito Un índice entero que permite acceder a las personas de la lista por número de documento. Por
ejemplo p=lista[30456345] devuelve el objeto Persona que tiene DNI=30456345 o null en caso que no exista en la lista.
Un índice de tipo char que devuelve un arreglo de strings con todos los nombres de las personas de la lista que comienzan con el carácter índice. Por ejemplo arreglo=lista['L'] devuelve todos los nombres de las personas que comienzan con L.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
namespace ejercicio8
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Persona n = new Persona("Martin",43057013,'M');
            Persona e = new Persona("Leandro",43111111,'M');
            Persona m = new Persona("Juan",42222222,'M');
            Persona t = new Persona("Lucas",43333333,'M');
            ListaDePersonas p = new ListaDePersonas();
            p.Agregar(n);
            p.Agregar(e);
            p.Agregar(m);
            p.Agregar(t);

            Persona dni = p[43333333];
            if(dni !=null){ 
                Console.WriteLine($"Dni: {dni.DNI}, Nombre: {dni._nombre}, Sexo: {dni._sexo}");
            }
            else{
                Console.WriteLine($"null, la persona con dni 422222224 no existe");
            }

            string[] arreglo = p['L'];

            foreach (string nombres in arreglo){
                Console.WriteLine($"Nombres: {nombres}");
            }

        }
    }
    public class Persona{
        public int DNI{get;set;}
        public string _nombre{get;set;}
        public char _sexo{get;set;}
        public Persona(string nombre,int dni,char sexo){
            _nombre = nombre;
            DNI = dni;
            _sexo = sexo;
        }
    }
    class ListaDePersonas
    {
        private Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
        public void Agregar(Persona p)
        {
            ht[p.DNI] = p;
        }

        public Persona this[int i]
        {
            get{
                if(ht.ContainsKey(i)) return (Persona)ht[i];
                else return null;
            }
        }

        public string[] this[char i]
        {
            get{
                string[] arreglo = new string[ht.Count];
                if(ht.ContainsValue(i)){
                    ht.CopyTo(arreglo,i);
                    return arreglo;
                }
                else{
                    return arreglo;
                }     
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In Spanish, please

Comment: Ademas no dupliques la pregunta q ya la hiciste con anterioridad

Comment: se bugeo y no me dejaba realizarla correctamente

Comment: Borra una de las dos, o terminaran cerradas, en caso de dejar esta por favor dale un formato correcto a tu codigo para que se entienda mejor

Comment: ok, gracias, fijate ahora, podrias ayudarme?, gracias

Comment: tengo otra duda, la clase persona esta bien decladara? o deberia de hacerlo en la clase lista de persona, de ser asi como hago?..gracias

Comment: Si te puedo ayudar pero tienes q esperar a manana q ya es muy tarde y me voy a acostar

Answer (score 0):

Hola te puedo mostrar dos formas de hacerlo, para que todas funcionen tiene que agregar esto

`using System.Linq;` en sus referencias de paso sería bueno que le hecho un vistaso a esto le será de mucha ayuda https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/

```
   public string[] this[char i]
            {
                get
                {
                    return (from persona in ht.Values.Cast<Persona>()
                    where persona._nombre[0] == i
                    select persona._nombre).ToArray();
                }
            }
```

ahora en esta solución con el uso de linq lo que le digo es que me selecione del hashtable las persona que el primer caracter del nombre sea el `char` que se le pasa,
importante esta parte `ht.Cast<Persona>()` aquí hacemos un cast para convertir los `object` a su clase `Persona` y poder usar sus propiedades

la otra variante es esta

```
   public string[] this[char i]
            {
                get
                {
                    return ht.Values.Cast<Persona>()
                             .Where(p => p._nombre[0] == i)
                             .Select(p => p._nombre).ToArray();
                }
            }
```

aquí usamos linq igual, lo que a lo mejor esta sentencia le es más amigable, por pasos primero hacemos el `Cast` para convertir los `object` a `Persona` después el método `Where` que resive un expresión lambda le decimos dame todas las personas que la primera letra del nombre sea el `char` i, después con `Select` le decimos dame solo el nombre para poder quedarnos solamente con el nombre, y por último le hacemos `ToArray` xq su índice devuelve un arreglo de string

Comment: Unhandled exception. System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.DictionaryEntry' to type 'ejercicio8.Persona'.

Comment: Disculpa olvidé poner el value ya edité la respuesta, ya funciona, pruebe otra vez